# Use tupla(i,j) instead of a single variable(j)

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I want to create a tupla variable for this model p(i,j) instead of only variable p(j). 
I have to change it here and on the variables that impacts it.

### [Current model example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxb86.png)

### Code

```
def buildBaseModel():
    global nVars,nClauses,kbRulesLit,kbRulesProbMin,kbRulesProbMax,kbRulesCard,Q
    # Create Model
    m = pulp.LpProblem("Profit maximising problem",pulp.LpMaximize)

    nPsatVars = 2 ** nVars

    # Create variables p_i -->HERE SHOULD BE p[i]_[j]
    p = {}    
    for j in range(nPsatVars):
        p[j]=pulp.LpVariable(lowBound=0,cat='Continuous',name='p_'+str(j))

    #m += sum([p[j] for j in range(nPsatVars)]) --> HERE CHANGE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION

    # Create variables pai_i
    pai = {}
    for j in range(1,Q + 1):
        #pai[j] = kbRulesProb[j]
        pai[j]= pulp.LpVariable(lowBound=kbRulesProbMin[j],upBound=kbRulesProbMax[j],cat='Continuous',name='pai_'+str(j))        
    for j in range(Q + 1,nClauses + 1):
        pai[j]= pulp.LpVariable(lowBound=0,cat='Continuous',name='pai_'+str(j))

    # Create variables qp_i
    qp = {}
    for j in range(1,Q+1): #not first rule
        qp[j]=pulp.LpVariable(lowBound=0,cat='Continuous',name='qp_'+str(j))

    # Create variables qn_i
    qn = {}
    for j in range(1,Q+1): #not first rule
        qn[j]=pulp.LpVariable(lowBound=0,cat='Continuous',name='qn_'+str(j))

    #construct the matrix A
    A=np.array([[1] * nPsatVars] * (nClauses + 1))#0
    x = {}
    for j in range(nVars):
        x[j] = 0
    for i in range(1,nClauses + 1):
        for j in range(nPsatVars):
            r = j
            #the value of x is the assignment of the Var,such as [0,1,1,0,0,0]
            for k in range(nVars):
                x[k] = (r >> k)%2
            t = 0
            for k in kbRulesLit[i]:
                if k == 0 and x[0] == 1:
                    t = 1
                if k > 0 and x[k] == 1:
                    t = 1
                if k < 0 and x[-k] == 0:
                    t = 1
            if t == 1:
                A[i][j] = 0

    #constrict
        m+=sum([p[j] for j in range(nPsatVars)])== 1.0 

        #constrict
        for i in range(1,Q + 1):
            m+=sum([p[j]*A[i][j] for j in range(nPsatVars)])-qp[i] <= kbRulesProbMax[i]

        for i in range(1,Q + 1):
            m+=sum([p[j]*A[i][j] for j in range(nPsatVars)])+qn[i] >= kbRulesProbMin[i]

        for i in range(Q + 1,nClauses + 1):
            m+=sum([p[j] * A[i][j] for j in range(nPsatVars)]) - pai[i] == 0 

    #USE GUROBI
    m.solve(pulp.GUROBI())
    pulp.LpStatus[m.status]

    if(m.status==-1):
        print("there is no solution for the CONDSAT problem")
    else :
        print("find solution\n")

    varsdict = {}
    for v in m.variables():
        print(v.name,"=", v.varValue)
    m.writeLP('c.lp')
```

[Final Model that the code should do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3351l.png)
So at final model we will have p_i_j instead of p_j like this code generate today.

besides this, I need help to change the objective function of the model is to add an objective function that maximize the sum of all variables p(i,j) (that needs to be done after the first change)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!.

Trying to implement your pasted LP model verbatim:

```
from pulp import *

prob = LpProblem("two_index", LpMaximize)

# ASSUME q is a constant
q = 0.5

# DECLARE sets of indices
set_I = range(1, 3)
set_J = range(0, 8)
set_K = range(1, 4)

# Declare variables n and p
p = LpVariable.dicts("p", (set_I, set_J))
n = LpVariable.dicts("n", (set_I, set_K))

# Define OBJECTIVE
prob += p[1][7] + p[2][7]

# Declare CONSTRAINTS
prob += p[1][0] + p[1][1] + p[1][2] + p[1][3] + p[1][4] + p[1][5] + p[1][6] + p[1][7] == 1 
prob += p[1][5] + p[1][7] - q*p[1][1] <= 0.75
prob += p[1][5] + p[1][7] + q*n[1][1] >= 0.71
prob += p[1][3] - q*p[1][2] <= 0.14
prob += p[1][3] + q*n[1][2] >= 0.14
prob += p[1][1] + q*p[1][3] <= 0.13
prob += p[1][1] - q*n[1][3] >= 0.13
prob += p[2][0] + p[2][1] + p[2][2] + p[2][3] + p[2][4] + p[2][5] + p[2][6] + p[2][7] == 1 
prob += p[2][5] + p[2][7] -  q*p[2][1] <= 0.35
prob += p[2][5] + p[2][7] +  q*n[2][1] >= 0.35
prob += p[2][3] - q*p[2][2] <= 0.41
prob += p[2][3] + q*n[2][2] >= 0.41
prob += p[2][1] + q*p[2][3] <= 0.29
prob += p[2][1] - q*n[2][3] >= 0.29

for i in set_I:
    for j in set_J:
        p[i][j] >= 0

    for k in set_K:
        q*p[i][k] >= 0
        q*n[i][k] >= 0

# Solve LP
prob.solve()
print (("Status:"), LpStatus[prob.status])

# Print result
for v in prob.variables(): 
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
print("objective=", value(prob.objective))
```

Which apparently results in an unbounded problem, hard to say for sure if this is right - I just implemented the model as I found it (didn't try to understand it).

```
Status: Unbounded
n_1_1 = 0.0
n_1_2 = 0.0
n_1_3 = -0.14
n_2_1 = 0.0
n_2_2 = 0.0
n_2_3 = -0.41
p_1_0 = 0.09
p_1_1 = 0.06
p_1_2 = 0.0
p_1_3 = 0.14
p_1_4 = 0.0
p_1_5 = 0.71
p_1_6 = 0.0
p_1_7 = 0.0
p_2_0 = 0.155
p_2_1 = 0.085
p_2_2 = 0.0
p_2_3 = 0.41
p_2_4 = 0.0
p_2_5 = 0.35
p_2_6 = 0.0
p_2_7 = 0.0
objective= 0.0
```